# How to deal with large vocab_size when training a Language Model in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, out-of-memory, language-model

I want to train a language model in Keras, by this tutorial:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-word-based-neural-language-models-python-keras/

My input is composed of:
lines num: 4823744
maximum line: 20
Vocabulary Size: 790609
Total Sequences: 2172328
Max Sequence Length: 11

As you can see by this lines:

```
num_words = 50
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_words, lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([data])
# determine the vocabulary size
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

I'm using the tokenizer with num_words=50. 
The vocab_size is taken from the tokenizer, but it's still the bigger size (790K).

Therefore this line:

```
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
```

Causes a memory error.

This is the model definition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 10, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
```

How can I deal with it?

I do want to have word-level model and not char-level. 
And I do want to take at least 10K of the most common words.

I thought about filtering words before hand, but it may cause the language model to learn false sequences.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fasttext is a better way to compute embeddings for large vocabularies - it does not need a dictionary entry for every word.

Answer (score 0):

reduce the batch size. It worked for me when I reduced batch size for 10000 to 500

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).